Returning results and throwing errors from closure within a function
I wish to throw errors and/or return request results from a closure. I went through some posts on SO and looks like people are mainly passing completion blocks to propogate error and result to the calling function.
I have a chain of functions (sometimes 3 function chain and sometimes 4-5), which means I will have to pass completion blocks to every function. Am trying to figure out if there is a better way to return result and errors from closure within a function.
BTW I am using MSGraph API here.
Code - Request functions:
private func processRequest(_ request: NSMutableURLRequest, completion: @escaping(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) throws -> ()) rethrows {
    let dataTask: MSURLSessionDataTask = httpClient.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            let statusCode = response.statusCode
            if (statusCode < 200) || (statusCode > 299) {
                let description = "Microsoft Graph service returned HTTP response status \(statusCode) for URL \(request.url?.absoluteString ?? "")"
                let error = NSError(code: statusCode, localizedDescription: description)
                try? completion(nil, nil, error)
            }
        }
        
        if let error = error {
            try? completion(nil, nil, error)
        }

        try? completion(data, response, nil)
    })
    
    dataTask.execute()
}

private func processRequestWithToken(_ request: NSMutableURLRequest, completion: (Data?, URLResponse?) -> ()) async throws {
    try await MicrosoftAccount.acquireToken()
    try processRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            throw error
        }
        
        completion(data, response)
    }
}

Code - Calling functions:
This below functions throws an error - Cannot convert value of type {'Bool' or '[MSGraphEvent]'} to closure result type '()', obviously because I am not returning a completion block.
public func cancelBooking(eventId: String) async throws -> Bool {
    let request = makeRequest(relativeUrl: "/me/events/\(eventId)/cancel", httpMethod: "POST")
    addStandardRequestHeaders(to: request)

    self.processRequestWithToken(request) { data, response in
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 202 {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

public func getEvents(selectedDate: Date?) async throws -> [MSGraphEvent] {
        var api = "/me/calendar/events?"

        let request = self.makeRequest(relativeUrl: api, httpMethod: "GET")
        self.processRequestWithToken(request) { data, response in
            let events: [MSGraphEvent] = try self.parseCollection(data: data)
            return events
        }
}

CancelBooking and getEvents functions are then called by another function. If I return a completion block to them, then I don't see any errors and everything works fine, but I have to pass completion block to every function in the chain.
Is there a better way I can propagate the results up in the function chain without passing completion block as parameters for every function?

You should try to only work with async/await.

I have been using async/await all across my app, but unfortunately that's not working here. If you notice the code, I am not using NSURLSession, it's 'MSURLSessionDataTask'. It's a Microsoft API. If I do "let (data, response) = try await httpClient.dataTask(with: request)", I get an error to add completion handler in data task.

Ok, I googled and it looks like this is very old SDK predating async/await. You still have the possibility though to use async/await if you use continuations, see for instance this article

Thanks! I will check out continuations. I have never heard of them, but the article you shared looks promising. I came across DispatchGroup and that solved my problem, but somehow I am not feeling confident with it. I also tried TaskGroups, but I was getting some weird errors. I will share the code for dispatch group below.

Thanks @JoakimDanielson! Continuation worked better for me.

DispatchGroup was crashing on me sometimes especially incase of bad request. Continuation worked better and the code is also nice and concise.
private func processRequest(_ request: NSMutableURLRequest, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ response: URLResponse?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    let dataTask: MSURLSessionDataTask = httpClient.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            let statusCode = response.statusCode
            if (statusCode < 200) || (statusCode > 299) {
                // create some error
                completion(nil, nil, error)
                return
            }
        }
        
        if let error = error {
            completion(nil, nil, error)
            return
        }

        completion(data, response, nil)
        return
    })
    
    dataTask.execute()
}

private func processRequestWithToken(_ request: NSMutableURLRequest) async throws -> (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?) {
    try await acquireToken()
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        processRequest(request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, requestError: Error?) in
            if let requestError = requestError {
                continuation.resume(throwing: requestError)
            } else {
                continuation.resume(returning: (data: data, response: response))
            }
        }
    }
}


This problem of chaining completion handlers is often called "Callback Hell" or "The Pyramid of Doom" and is specifically addressed by the Async/Await paradigm.
A challenge to answering your question is that the answer is simply "learn to use async/await" and apply it to your problem domain.
I recommend you start with "Meet async/await in Swift" which describes the pyramid of doom and how async/await addresses the issue:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132/

Actually in Swift "pyramid of doom" usually refers to something else (nested if let).

Pyramid of Doom refers to both callbacks and if checks (particularly nil checks). See:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming) -- "the pyramid of doom is commonly seen when checking for null pointers or handling callbacks"

I have been using async/await all across my app, but unfortunately that's not working here. If you notice the code, I am not using NSURLSession, it's 'MSURLSessionDataTask'. It's a Microsoft API. If I do "let (data, response) = try await httpClient.dataTask(with: request)", I get an error to add completion handler in data task.

@tech_human the technique to take a synchronous API with a callback and integrate it with asysc/await is to use the withCheckedContinuation withCheckedThrowingContinuation functions

Thanks @ScottThompson! Continuation worked better for me.

I came across DispatchGroup and that's one way which helped me to solve my problem. Sharing the code for it below.
I will also try Joakim's suggestion and will share it's code as well.
private func processRequest(_ request: NSMutableURLRequest) -> (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    var result: (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) = (nil, nil, nil)
    dispatchGroup.enter()
        
    let dataTask: MSURLSessionDataTask = httpClient.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            let statusCode = response.statusCode
            if (statusCode < 200) || (statusCode > 299) {
                let description = "Microsoft Graph service returned HTTP response status \(statusCode) for URL \(request.url?.absoluteString ?? "")"
                let error = NSError(code: statusCode, localizedDescription: description)
                result = (nil, nil, error)
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
            
        if let error = error {
            result = (nil, nil, error)
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }

        result = (data, response, nil)
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    })
        
    dataTask.execute()
        
    dispatchGroup.wait()
    return result
}

private func processRequestWithToken(_ request: NSMutableURLRequest) async throws -> (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?) {
    try await acquireToken()
    let result = processRequest(request)
    if let error = result.error {
        throw error
    }
        
    return (data: result.data, response: result.response)
}

